# Inaccurate Camera Pose results

Tags: c++, opencv, camera-calibration, homography

I am trying to measure the camera pose relative to a fiducial marker. I am measuring a marker similar to this here: http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=4r6k3q&s=8#.VNgsgzVVK1F

My code is shown below. I have no trouble finding matches and even drawing a box around the match.

I've compared the camera pose to physical measurements, and the camera pose is definitely off by about a **half meter**. I wouldn't be surprised if there were minor errors, but a half meter struck me as a pretty large error.

At first, I thought it was my camera calibration, since there is significant distortion due to fish-eyed lenses. I recalibrated, but this apparently was not the issue.

I've been looking through my code to see if anything sticks out as the problem, but haven't seen it. Might be the case of looking at the code too long and it might be obvious to someone.

```
//Load  marker & scene images
Mat marker, scene;
marker = imread(FILE1, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);
scene = imread(FILE2, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_UNCHANGED);

//Check to make sure both images were loaded
if( marker.empty() || scene.empty() ) {
    cout << "Error: image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
}

//Convert marker & scene images to grayscale
cvtColor(marker, marker, CV_RGB2GRAY);
cvtColor(scene, scene, CV_RGB2GRAY);

//Detect keypoints using ORB Detector
SiftFeatureDetector detector;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints1, keypoints2; 
detector.detect(marker, keypoints1);
detector.detect(scene, keypoints2);

//Extract descriptors
SiftDescriptorExtractor extractor;
Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;
extractor.compute( marker, keypoints1, descriptors1 );
extractor.compute( scene, keypoints2, descriptors2 );

//Brute Force Match descriptors from marker to scene
BFMatcher matcher(NORM_L2, true);
vector<DMatch> matches;
matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

//Set arbitrary min and max distances between keypoints
double min_dist = 10000;
double max_dist = 0;

//Calculate the min and max distances between keypoints
for( int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++ ) { 
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if( dist < min_dist ) min_dist = dist;
    if( dist > max_dist ) max_dist = dist;
}

//Define good matches
std::vector< DMatch > good_matches;
for( int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++ ) {
    if( matches[i].distance <= max(2*min_dist, 90.0) ) { //90 was found through quick experimenting, this may or may not be optimal.
        good_matches.push_back( matches[i]); 
    }
}

//Exit program if there are an insufficient number of matches
if ( good_matches.size() < 4) {
    cout << "Error: image cannot be loaded..!!" << endl;
    system("pause");
    return -1;
} 

//Draw good matches
Mat matchesImage;
drawMatches( marker, keypoints1, scene, keypoints2,
    good_matches, matchesImage, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1),
    vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

//Find the coordinates of the source and target points 
vector<Point2f> srcPoints, dstPoints;

for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    srcPoints.push_back(keypoints1[good_matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    dstPoints.push_back(keypoints2[good_matches[i].trainIdx].pt);
}

//Find homography
Mat H;
H = findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints, CV_RANSAC);

//Get corners of marker //pixels
vector<Point2f> marker_corners(4);
marker_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
marker_corners[1] = cvPoint(marker.cols, 0);
marker_corners[2] = cvPoint(marker.cols, marker.rows);
marker_corners[3] = cvPoint(0, marker.rows);

vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);

//Perform perspective transform
perspectiveTransform(marker_corners, scene_corners, H);

//Draw lines between corners
line(matchesImage, scene_corners[0] + Point2f(marker.cols, 0), scene_corners[1] + Point2f(marker.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(matchesImage, scene_corners[1] + Point2f(marker.cols, 0), scene_corners[2] + Point2f(marker.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(matchesImage, scene_corners[2] + Point2f(marker.cols, 0), scene_corners[3] + Point2f(marker.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);
line(matchesImage, scene_corners[3] + Point2f(marker.cols, 0), scene_corners[0] + Point2f(marker.cols,0), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 4);

//Open calibration file
FileStorage fs2("calibration.xml", FileStorage::READ);

//Read in camera matrix and distortion coefficients
Mat cameraMatrix, distCoeffs;
fs2["Camera_Matrix"] >> cameraMatrix;
fs2["Distortion_Coefficients"] >> distCoeffs;
fs2.release();

//Define marker corners in 3d
vector<Point3f> objp1(4);
marker_corners_3d[0] = cvPoint3D32f(0,0,0);
marker_corners_3d[1] = cvPoint3D32f(marker.cols, 0, 0);
marker_corners_3d[2] = cvPoint3D32f(marker.cols, marker.rows, 0);
marker_corners_3d[3] = cvPoint3D32f(0, marker.rows, 0);

//Find Object Pose
solvePnPRansac( marker_corners_3d, scene_corners, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rvec, tvec );

//Convert rotation vector to rotation matrix
Mat R;
Rodrigues(rvec, R);

//solvePnPRansac found the pose of the marker relative to the camera.
//Need to find the pose of the camera relatiive to the marker...
//Transpose matrix
R = R.t();

//Convert back to rotation vector
Rodrigues(R,rvec);

//Find the translation vector of camera relative to marker
tvec = -R*tvec;

//Define the camera pose matrix
Mat camPose = Mat::eye(4, 4, R.type());
R.copyTo(camPose.rowRange(0,3).colRange(0,3));
tvec.copyTo(camPose.rowRange(0,3).colRange(3,4));

}
```

Comment: Any thoughts from anyone?

Comment: Looks like link to image is broken, can you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a similar problem. After camera calibration and PnP, I used the result Tvec and Rvec and ProjectPoints to draw a 3D cube, it seems pretty accurate, but compared to physical world measure meant it was off by probably half a meter.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oztfl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31156039)